# Formula or Macro to auto increment cells in the same column by 1 when a enter is hit

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Good day friends

I must admit i am a bit rusty with this so i am asking help from you guys..any feedback would be greatly appreciated

I am doing a spreadsheet which contains receipt numbers that are entered and a value associated with it in the adjacent corresponding column

I want to create a formula for the Column"D" that auto increments the previous value of the (receipt number) by one when the a enter is hit or a assign a command button to do so...basically when i input the value of the first receipt the next cell will be incremented by one..the cell under that will be incremented by one of the previous value..or the initial value plus 2 plus 3 etc

Example

D Column

```
D1     567890
D2     567891
D3     567892
D4     567893
```

Thanks a lot for any help rendered guys

Comment: In `D2` use formula: `=D1+1` and then highlight the cell and drag down the column by selecting the little black box in the lower right corner of the highlighted cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is more automatic than a formula:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Static inswitch&
  Dim iRow&, iCol&
  If inswitch = 1 Then Exit Sub ' prevent looping
  iRow = Target.Row
  iCol = Target.Column
  If iCol <> 4 Then Exit Sub
  If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) = "" Then ' check needed?
    inswitch = 1
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) = Cells(iRow, iCol) + 1
    inswitch = 0
  End If
End Sub
```